# Outlook mail metrics vba mismatch type

Tags: vba, outlook

Trying to use the vba from another thread, however, getting a mismatch type on the line for "For Each olMail In flInbox.Items".  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I have outlook and excel referenced.

```
Dim olMail As MailItem
Dim aOutput() As Variant
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim flInbox As Folder

Set flInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

ReDim aOutput(1 To flInbox.Items.Count, 1 To 4)

For Each olMail In flInbox.Items
    If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" Then
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        aOutput(lCnt, 1) = olMail.SenderEmailAddress 'maybe stats on domain
        aOutput(lCnt, 2) = olMail.ReceivedTime 'stats on when received
        aOutput(lCnt, 3) = olMail.ConversationTopic 'group based on subject w/o regard to prefix
        aOutput(lCnt, 4) = olMail.Subject 'to split out prefix
    End If
Next olMail

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlSh = xlApp.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)

xlSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput
xlApp.Visible = True
```

Link:

[Using VBA in Outlook to gather statistics on received emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404224/using-vba-in-outlook-to-gather-statistics-on-received-emails/34045167#34045167)

Comment: May the folder you are testing with does not contain mails only? Maybe also other folders?

Comment: Hey blckbird. Not sure what you mean? Its my normal Inbox, it doesnt have subfolders.  Just Inbox, Drafts, Sent Mail, Deleteted Items.  The default Outlook setup.

Answer (score 1):

You For Each loop assumes that the object obtained from the indexer of the Items collection is returning a MailItem object into the olMail variable. That folder could contain non-email messages, such as ReportItem or MeetingRequest objects.  Instead declare an Object variable, and check the value of MessageClass or Type to verify that the message is a MailItem object before you cast it to a specific object time.  I would also use a For loop with an indexer instead of For Each, which consumes less memory resources when iterating Outlook objects.

Comment: Better yet: `If TypeOf obj Is MailItem Then ...`

Comment: You guys are awesome! Changed olMail to Variant and worked like a charm!  One day I hope to be as good as you, until then, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @user Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. This shows your appreciation and closes the thread.